# Mail mirroring / monitoring in Linux

Tags: linux, email, postfix

As one of my client asked to monitor corporate emails (from and to), I needed a solution. I find a Windows based solution (Hmailserver) which allows mirroring of emails to a specified address.

But as we also consider some web services, I wondered if there is any mail server which can do same thing in Linux? Or any modification to a common package like Postfix?

Thank you

Comment: This is probably better answered on Serverfault, but I have in the past done this on both postfix and exim.  I remember it being easier on exim, but that may just be crazy talk.  The need I had was parents tapping into their children's email, and so they got everything sent and received.  At one point, the parents decided it was no longer needed, and so the configuration was removed and I do not have it any longer (thus the comment rather than an answer with code)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this feature with Postfix:

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#always_bcc
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_bcc_maps